# Using the stackdriver gem with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am interested in playing around with the various stackdriver offerings, but I can't seem to get it to work with Rails. I added `stackdriver` to my Gemfile, ran `bundle install` and have added the config blocks.

Here's the error I am getting:

```
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `google_cloud' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fbc843e0c18> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/preston/projects/myapp/config/environments/development.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

I have tried requiring the Gem manually, among other things, and it doesn't seem like the code is getting loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue that was causing an old version of the stackdriver gem (0.2.2) to be used. This happened due to a conflict with a different Google gem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. How were you able to resolve this?